# Drop or select columns from multiple pandas dataframe with no headers

Tags: python, dataframe

I am working on a unstructured data, there are data coming from a **tool** equipment. There is lot of noise in the data by having extra columns with no information.

For example, I am getting the data for the past 7 days in 7 different files, I need to drop same number or set of columns from all these 7 files. I believe there is a better and efficient way to drop columns of these 7 files.

I appreciate if you could take a look at my code and suggest me a way to drop or select only the required columns efficiently.

This is what I have tried so far,

```
df1.drop(df1.columns[[4,9,10,11,12,13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22,23, 25, 28, 30,32, 31, 33]], axis=1, inplace=True) 

df2.drop(df2.columns[[4,9,10,11,12,13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22,23, 25, 28, 30,32, 31, 33]], axis=1, inplace=True)

df3.drop(df3.columns[[4,9,10,11,12,13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22,23, 25, 28, 30,32, 31, 33]], axis=1, inplace=True) 

df4.drop(df4.columns[[4,9,10,11,12,13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22,23, 25, 28, 30,32, 31, 33]], axis=1, inplace=True) 

df5.drop(df5.columns[[4,9,10,11,12,13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22,23, 25, 28, 30,32, 31, 33]], axis=1, inplace=True) 

df6.drop(df6.columns[[4,9,10,11,12,13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22,23, 25, 28, 30,32, 31, 33]], axis=1, inplace=True) 

df7.drop(df7.columns[[4,9,10,11,12,13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22,23, 25, 28, 30,32, 31, 33]], axis=1, inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a list of data frames,

```
dfs = [list of dataframes]
```

Create a list of columns to be dropped

```
cols = [4,9,10,11,12,13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22,23, 25, 28, 30,32, 31, 33]
```

Use this,

```
for df in dfs:
    df.drop(df.columns[cols],axis=1,inplace=True)
```

Otherwise, list comprehension way,

```
dfs = [df.drop(df.columns[cols],axis=1) for df in dfs]
```

Comment: Would it be possible to apply this drop code to all the files in one line instead of running it on every single dataframe?     FYI: I am not able to concat before dropping the columns and adding column headers since the data is unstructured.

Comment: dfs=['df1', 'df2', 'df3', 'df4', 'df5', 'df6', 'df6', 'df7']

cols=[4,9,10,11,12,13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22,23, 25, 28, 30,32, 31, 33]
for df in dfs:
    df.drop(df.columns[cols],axis=1,inplace=True)
dfs = [df.drop(df.columns[cols],axis=1) for df in dfs]                      I am getting a attribute error ('str' object has no attribute 'drop')

Comment: @Vishwas `dfs = ['df1', 'df2', ...]` is a list of strings. `[df1, ds2, ...]` is a list of dataframes. see the difference?

Comment: Thank you for your help, please take a look at my code.                      dfs=[df1, df2, df3, df4, df5, df6, df6, df7]

cols=[4,9,10,11,12,13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22,23, 25, 28, 30,32, 31, 33]
for df in dfs: 
    df.drop(df.columns[cols], axis=1, inplace=True)

dfs = [df.drop(df.columns[cols], axis=1) for df in dfs]                           IndexError: index 13 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 13

Comment: I am really sorry to bother you again, when I run either one of them (for loop or list comprehension) , I still get index error. I am not sure if this is because the data is unstructured?

Comment: I get 8, when type len(dfs)

Comment: @Vishwas how many columns do you have in each dataframe? Above answer would give the output as you iriginally asked if you have the same number of columns in each dataframe and they have the same name.

Comment: Individual dataframe or file have 35 columns and I am dropping 22 columns, so I am left 13 columns in dataframe. So total I have 13 columns.

Answer (score 0):

```
def concatenate (indir="//xxyyzz/xyx/Profile/Desktop/Error_log_data", outfile="//xxyyzz/xyz/Profile/Desktop/Error_log_data//concat.csv"):
    os.chdir(indir)
    fileList=glob.glob("*.csv")
    dfList=[]
    colnames=[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34]
    for filename in fileList:
        print(filename)
        df=pd.read_csv(filename, header=None)
        dfList.append(df)
    concatDf=pd.concat(dfList, axis=0)
    concatDf.columns=colnames
    concatDf.to_csv(outfile, index=None)
    concatenate()
df_err=pd.read_csv("//xxxyyyxx/xyz/Profile/Desktop/Error_log_data//concat.csv")
df=df_err[['0','1','2','3','5','6','7','8','9','24','26','27','29','34']]. rename(columns{'0':"Err_Class",'1':"Err_Code",'2':"Date_time",'3':"Microseconds",'5':"Err_Source",'6':"Err_Type",'7':"Err_Text1",'8':"Err_Text2",'9':"Err_Code_link",'24':"ToolID" ,'26':"Component1" ,'27':"Component2" ,
'29':"X_number" ,'34':"END"})
```